# Interpret correlation coefficient using correlation matrix

Tags: python, dataframe, correlation, cross-correlation

I want to apply a regression algorithm but before that I decided to study the relationship between my target output(Temperature value) and the remaining variables so I decided to plot the correlation matrix as a first step.
I got the next picture :

[image]

As it is shown the Image below : the Temperature is strongly correlated with the first 4 variables

Based on a the difference between VBATT and VIN I decided to split the total samples into two subsets : subset1 and subset 2. Then, I plotted the correlation variables

Subset 1:  VIN-VBATT> X

[image]

Subset 2: VIN-VBATT=< x

[image]

I can not understand why the correlation between the Temperature and VIN has changed completely ?
And why all the correlation coefficients has been decreased ?

Thank you in adavance !

Comment: See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/239673/159540).

Comment: @DavidM. I think that the answer explain the situation but How I can Interpret my situation? Especially,  Simpson's Paradox

Comment: The interpretation is case-specific; it depends on what the variables mean and how they are distributed. You could start by plotting `Temperature` against `VIN` for your two subsets of `VIN-BATT`. See [this example](https://towardsdatascience.com/simpsons-paradox-how-to-prove-two-opposite-arguments-using-one-dataset-1c9c917f5ff9).